# Hide SKU in new order email template

Tags: woocommerce, hide, sku

How do I customize `woocommerce_email_order_meta` to hide the SKU?

I see snippets like this but it also hides them in the product page. I only want to hide the SKU in New Order email.

```
function sv_remove_product_page_skus( $enabled ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'wc_product_sku_enabled', 'sv_remove_product_page_skus' );
```

Let me know your thoughts, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Look in email-order-items.php
You see this line

```
// SKU.
if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
echo wp_kses_post( ‘ (#’ . $sku . ‘)’ );
}
```

You can comment out the echo line with // so:

```
// SKU.
if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
  // echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $sku . ')' );
}
```